# How to search text stored in a variable?

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings | grep -oE '[0-9]+'|sort -rn|head -n 1)
key=$(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings)
newnum=$(grep -oE '[0-9]+' $key |sort -rn|head -n 1)
echo $newnum
```

`grep` takes the `$key` as filename, but I want it to search the text stored in the variable `$text`.

Comment: `echo "${key}" | grep ...`

Comment: @AndyDalton , imo this is the solution that OP is looking for and should be put as an answer , not a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use herestring `<<<` to pass the string to grep:

```
newnum=$(grep -oE '[0-9]+' <<< "$key" | sort -rn | head -n 1)
```

That would be more efficient than `echo "$key" | grep` which would create an extra process.

Remember to enclose your variables in double quotes to prevent [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) and globbing.  See [this](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) as well.